# Deployments can not be encrypt by EncryptionConfig

Tags: kubernetes

I want to enable data encryption in etcd.

I followed the step described in the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/encrypt-data/).

1. Created config file as below:

   ```
   kind: EncryptionConfig  
   apiVersion: v1  
   resources:  
     - resources:      
       - secrets     
       - configmaps  
       - deployments  
       providers:  
       - aescbc:  
           keys:  
           - name: key1  
             secret: O804TNlPZ4PG+f5Ocbkg/VLfYW7bVxituFGCsAjWiQc=  
       - identity: {}
   ```
2. Set the encrypt config in kube-apiserver

   ```
   - experimental-encryption-provider-config=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-rest.key
   ```
3. After restart kube-apiserver, create a configmap and deployment resource,
4. Check data if is encrypt in etcd. configmap and secret resource is encrypt, but deployment is not encrypt. And for crd resources, is not encrypt also.
   [image]

Does encryptionconfig only support several kind resources, not all kind resource, I do not see any description about supported kind of resources in the kubernetes documentation.

Comment: According to the documentation and the code, encryption should work for any resource, consequently for a Deployment too. Could you share logs for your API-server with verbose logging enabled (`--v=4`)